# Reversing a list. Problem with appending to lists in Ruby

Tags: ruby, list, append, slice

So, I've been trying to reverse a list in Ruby.

Here is the code:

```
def reverse(arr)
    retval = []
    arr.each do |e| 
        retval =  [e] << retval[0..retval.length]
    end 
    return retval
end

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
res = reverse(arr)  
puts "[" + res * ", " + "]"
```

The expected output is:

```
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Result:

```
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, ]
```

I believe `[e] << retval[0..retval.length]` does not append properly here. I think instead of, for example, `[1] << [] = [1]` I get `[1] << [] = [1, []]`.
Any idea how do I fix this?

**Note**: Please do not suggest any other way how to reverse a list. Thank you :)

Comment: Try `p res` to print the result.

Comment: What is p res? @Stefan

Comment: The problem was that my resulting array was like this: [5, [4, [3, [2, [1, [ ] ] ] ] ] ] ]. I was intending to get [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] and if the reverse logic had been correct, I would have gotten that answer.

Comment: Why don't you just use the build-in method [`Array#reverse`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/Array.html#method-i-reverse)? And to output the result you could just use [`Kernel#p`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/Kernel.html#method-i-p). This means `p arr.reverse` is the Ruby equivalent to your code.

Comment: @Sakhund _"What is p res?"_ – it prints `res` but (as opposed to `puts`) will use the object's `inspect` method which usually reveals the structure of the object.

Answer (score -2):

Never mind, I found the solution. It had simple yet vital mistake. I wrote  `+` the concatenation operator instead of `<<` and it fixed it. Here is the full code:

```
def reverse(arr)
    retval = []
    arr.each do |e| 
        retval =  [e] + retval[0..retval.length]
    end 
    return retval
end

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
res = reverse(arr)  
puts "[" + res * ", " + "]"
```

Comment: `retval[0..retval.length]` is just `retval`